# accessing a text box inside a grid with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a lable and multiple textboxes and a button inside a gridView, I need to access these textboxes when clicking on that button, here's what my code looks like..

```
<asp:GridView id="grdEventProfile" runat="server" >
    <Columns>

    <asp:BoundField DataField="EventID" SortExpression="EventID" HeaderText="Event ID"></asp:BoundField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="txtEventDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EventRecognitionDate") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label id="Label4" runat="server" "Text='<%# Bind("EventRecognitionDate") %>'></asp:Label> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox id="txtTaskDueDate" Text='<%# Bind("TaskDueDate") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label id="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TaskDueDate") %>'></asp:Label> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button id="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="EDT" OnClientClick = "AllowEdit()" ></asp:Button> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

in my JavaScript function AllowEdit(), I want be able to do something like this

```
if ( EventID == 01 && txtEventDate.value == 0 )
    txtTaskDueDate.Enabled = False;
```

I can not access my textboxes or lables by document.getElementByID because they are placed inside a grid.

I also tried this approach:

```
var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grdEventProfile.ClientID%>');
var elements = grid.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

but turns out it only works with (onChange) attribute, but not onClientClick.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you not try it on server side?

Comment: It's a group project and I'm not supposed to change anything on the server side, I was hoping I would be able to do it on the client side! 

So are you saying it isn't doable with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

The GridView has rows, so you need to specify the correct row number first before you can access the TextBox.

```
var value = document.getElementById('<%= grdEventProfile.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>').value;
```

Or loop them all and get the correct one.

```
$('#<%= grdEventProfile.ClientID %> input[type="text"]').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("ID"));
});
```

Comment: how can I know the row number of the row being edited?? Because I only want to execute my code for the textboxes associated with that particular button that was clicked..

Comment: In a GridView you have `Container.DataItemIndex`, that will give you the row number.

Comment: unfortunately using the approach, (var value = document.getElementById('<%= grdEventProfile.Rows[i].FindControl("TextBox1").ClientID %>').value;) gives me an error: Expression does not produce a value